# How to show some custom message in status Bar of iOS

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, statusbar

I want to show some custom text in statusBar like the Uber app is showing when we open another app over Uber. Uber is showing "**Uber is actively using your location **" when we open another app over Uber. Can anyone help me? How can I achieve this? I have attached screenshot for your reference.

[image: Attached Uber App Screenshot]

I'm expecting similar kind of behaviour like after opening the Uber app if we open any other app over Uber then I want to show some custom message in status bar place like Uber is displaying. I have seen some questions that are similar already posted but they are very old posts and my question is bit different.

Comment: You can’t. That’s a privacy alert that is no longer being used. Best you could do is a push notification but it won’t stay on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

on IOS 11, apple removed Blue Bar Banner that display for apps that used location.

```
open var showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: Bool
```

**From Apple:**

This property affects only apps that received always authorization. When such an app moves to the background, the system uses this property to determine whether to change the status bar appearance to indicate that location services are in use. Displaying a modified status bar gives the user a quick way to return to your app. The default value of this property is NO.

For apps with when-in-use authorization, the system always changes the status bar appearance when the app uses location services in the background.

'**showsBackgroundLocationIndicator**' (set true) is the indicator to allow this or deny it